# Assembly '' references assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap, ', which is not present in the current database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, assemblies, dts

I created an assembly of microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap as my code got this dependency.
It created the assembly succesfully.

So when I created an assembly of my script as follow :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY transfer8555
FROM 'C:\Users\transferTask\Transfer\bin\Debug\Transfer.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

it returns me this error :

> Assembly 'Transfer' references assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap, version=11.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

Comment: Potentially a silly question but have you tried to *load the referenced assembly into the current database*?

Comment: @iamdave yes i did it, actually it appears in Programmability>Assemblies

Comment: You need to add another reference to that one dtsruntimewrap.  If you add an assembly to your project it can have dependencies that are included in your app dependencies but they are not built into SQL assembly, so you need to add it first

Comment: @Brad I've already created an assembly with the dtsruntimewrap.dll file. It appears in the Assemblies node of my db. But when try to add the other depencies it renders me the same error.

Comment: Is it the correct version that the error says your missing:  version=11.0.0.0?

Comment: @Brad yes It's the correct version